# Error with 'tesseract/baseapi.h'

Tags: c++, opencv

When I run this program in opencv, I get the following error.

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tesseract/baseapi.h': No such file or directory

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <iostream>

// Covert RGB to CMYK using the formula from
void rgb2cmyk(cv::Mat& src, std::vector<cv::Mat>& cmyk)
{
    CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_8UC3);

    cmyk.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cmyk.push_back(cv::Mat(src.size(), CV_32F));

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j)
        {
            cv::Vec3b p = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j);

            float r = p[2] / 255.;
            float g = p[1] / 255.;
            float b = p[0] / 255.;
            float k = (1 - std::max(std::max(r,g),b));

            cmyk[0].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k); 
            cmyk[1].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k);
            cmyk[2].at<float>(i,j) = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k);
            cmyk[3].at<float>(i,j) = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check your include-directories. Posting your whole code here does not really help to solve this. Tesseract is an OCR library, as far as I know. I think its not directly related to OpenCV

Comment: Does your problem really occur during "running"? I assume it is during compilation.

Comment: yes during compilation

Answer (score 1):

Add the path of the header file directory in the "Additional Include Directories" of your project settings

Comment: can you tell me which header file ?

Comment: baseapi.h , Go to project properties-> C/C++ -> General-> Additonal Include Directories -> Edit -> browse to the directory which contains baseapi.h (tesseract) and add it